# cannot print out the table by xpath

Tags: python, xpath, beautifulsoup

can't print out //*[@class="footballmaincontent"] from the specific website by xpath, thanks!

```
# -*- coding:UTF-8 -*-

from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
import sys
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(1024, 768))
display.start()

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("url")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source.encode('utf-8'),'html.parser')
lines = soup.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="footballmaincontent"]/tr')
print lines

driver.close()
display.stop()
```

Comment: [`table[2]` only has a `tbody` inside it](https://imgur.com/a/AVvUUqJ)

Comment: thanks for your clarify, actually I want to get the table of //*[@class="footballmaincontent"] , thanks a lot !

Comment: There's only one element with the xpath `//*[@class="footballmaincontent"]`, so it's better if you call `find_elements_by_xpath` with this parameter. Please note it's a `DIV` rather than a `TABLE`, so it doesn't have a `TR` child tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bs4` has no such method as `find_elements_by_xpath()` - it's Selenium method.

Try below code:

```
lines = [event.text for event in driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@class="footballmaincontent"]//tr')]
print lines
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, dear !